# How to create sticky navigation both at top and at left

Tags: css, sass

I want to ask about a theory on how to create a sticky navigation like in this image:

[image]

What I think it should be like is that I first have to create the sidebar to be in fixed position, then in the main content create the searchbar with the profile image and the button. I do have it in my mind and tried it, but it got messed up. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this type of design or how I can approach it?

Answer (score -1):

try this. You just need to have 2 fixed blocks, one at left side, one at top, and add some padding and margin to not overlap each other.

```css
html,body{
  margin:0px
}
.main-sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 80px;
    min-height: 100%;
        background-color: #222d32;
}
.main-header{
  position: fixed !important;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 55px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    z-index:20
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidebar-menu>li {
    position: relative;
    padding:5px;
}
.header-menu li{
  display:inline-block;
  width:calc(100/5);
  padding:10px 5px
}
.sidebar-menu>li:hover >ul {
    display:block
}
.sidebar-menu>li>.treeview-menu {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0px;
    padding:10px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<header class="main-header">
  <nav>
    <ul class="header-menu">
      <li>inner menu1 </li>
      <li>inner menu2 </li>
      <li>inner menu3 </li>
     </ul>  
  </nav>
</header>
<aside class="main-sidebar">

    <section class="sidebar">

        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
          <li>menu1 
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li>inner menu1 </li>
              <li>inner menu2 </li>
              <li>inner menu3 </li>
            </ul>  
          </li>
          <li>menu2 
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li>inner menu1 </li>
              <li>inner menu2 </li>
              <li>inner menu3 </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>menu3 
            <ul class="treeview-menu">
              <li>inner menu1 </li>
              <li>inner menu2 </li>
              <li>inner menu3 </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>    
    </section>
</aside>
```